# Trying to run a function on an array in a, for loop, using jsrender

Tags: javascript, templates, jquery-templates, jsrender

Trying to convert very complex jQuery template code to jsRender.  I have this each loop in the old code:

```
<script id = "imagesTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
    {{each(i,imgUrl) twoAcross_filterOutMainImages(OfferGroup.Images)}}
        <img src="{{= imgUrl}}" />
    {{/each}}
</script>

<script id = "largeTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
    {{tmpl "#imagesTemplate"}}
</script>

<div id="LARGE"  class="mainContent"></div>
<script>
     currentOffer = offerGroups[0].Groups[0];
     $( "#LARGE" ).html( $( "#largeTemplate" ).render( currentOffer ) ); 
</script>
```

I have edited it to look like this:

```
{{for ~filterOutMainImages(Images) tmpl="#imagesTemplate"/}}

<div id="LARGE"  class="mainContent"></div>
<script>
     currentOffer = offerGroups[0].Groups[0];
     $( "#LARGE" ).html( $( "#largeTemplate" ).render( currentOffer ) ); 
</script>
```

But it does not work. If I change it to be:

```
<script id = "imagesTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">    
        <img src="{{= imgUrl}}" />
</script>

<script id = "largeTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
    {{for Images tmpl="#imagesTemplate"/}}
</script>

<div id="LARGE"  class="mainContent"></div>
<script>
     currentOffer = offerGroups[0].Groups[0];
      $( "#LARGE" ).html( $( "#largeTemplate" ).render( currentOffer ) ); 
</script>
```

It draws the images to display but the function does not run on the image array. But if I leave the Images array without being wrapped in a function and move the for loop to inside the template it breaks.

How would I convert this scenario?

Comment: How are you declaring your helper function: filterOutMainImages? Yes, showing a fiddle would be good... Should be {{:imgUrl}}.
That second version above is missing a <script> wrapper around the template...

Comment: I had a problem with setting it all up using fiddle interface so I posted a test page here:
http://www.mcgrathdesigns.com/test/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An important difference between JsRender and jQuery Templates is that JsRender does not let you access global functions or variables directly within template markup.

This is a design choice, related to security concerns, and separation of concerns. But unlike "logicless" template languages, such as Mustache, JsRender provides very powerful and flexible support for logic within the template - while still preventing random mixing of code and markup.

One way to include logic is to encapsulate it outside the template in helper functions, but in that case you need to ***register*** the helper function, either globally, or for the specific template, or else pass it in on an options object with the render call.

See [www.jsviews.com/#helpers](http://www.jsviews.com/#helpers) and [www.jsviews.com/#samples/jsr/helpers](http://www.jsviews.com/#samples/jsr/helpers) for documentation. (There are many other samples also on the [www.jsviews.com](http://www.jsviews.com) site showing use of helper functions)

So in your case you can do

```
function filterOutMainImages(images) { ... }

// Register helper
$.views.helpers({
    filterImages: filterOutMainImages 
});    

var html = $("#largeTemplate").render(currentOffer);

$("#LARGE").html(html);
```

Or

```
function filterOutMainImages(images) { ... }

var html = $("#largeTemplate").render(
    currentOffer,
    {filterImages: filterOutMainImages} // Pass in helper
);

$("#LARGE").html(html);
```

Assuming your filterOutMainImages() function returns a filtered array, and with your helper registered or passed in as above, then the following templates should work:

```
<script id = "imagesTemplate" type="text/x-jsrender">    
    <img src="{{>imgUrl}}" />
</script>

<script id = "largeTemplate" type="text/x-jsrender">
    {{for ~filterImages(Images) tmpl="#imagesTemplate"/}}
</script>
```

Comment: Actually Boris if you look at my test page it still seems to not be working.  http://mcgrathdesigns.com/test/ Is it the way I am writing the array?  It actually looks like it may be the way I am trying to call each item in the loop.  there does not seem to be an "handle EACH as..." I have written out a commented line in the top of the #LARGE div that shows the array is getting to the for loop.

Comment: got it just used #view.data as if it were array[i]in a for loop or each as in an each loop. So in your above example {{>imgUrl}} should be {{:#view.data}}

Comment: Well if your function returns an array of strings, it would be {{:#data}} - which is shorthand for {{:#view.data}}. Or you can encode using {{>#data}}, {{attr:#data} or {{url:#data}} - see http://www.jsviews.com/#converters(). I had assumed you returned an array of objects with imgUrl properties, given your previous versions.

Comment: wow awesome sophistication of your library!  Nice to have those options, great job. Thanks again.