# pass a dom level js object to a template function using jsrender

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-templates, jsrender

I simply want to pass in a javascript object that is populated by the template to a helper function. I have looked at conversations regarding passing in helper objects to loops but have not found anything that directly addresses the following example.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // an object set by the template
    var SomeObject = {};
    SomeObject.Id=6;
</script>
<script id = "SomeTemplate" type="text/html">
    <div id="somegroup_{{>Id}}" class="main">
        <img id="somegroup_img_{{>Id}}" class="mainImg" src="{{: ~fltrOAMnImgs_hlp(Images, SomeObject)}}"> 
    </div>
</script>
```

The current above code does not pass SomeObject to the helper func.
How could I do this with the new jsrender lib?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to provide access to your `SomeObject` within the template, you must pass that object in as a helper. There are some different ways to do that, depending on whether you want it available globally to all templates, just to this template, or just for this render() call. See: the $.views.helpers() topic under [Register helpers, converters, tags...](http://www.jsviews.com/#jsrregister)

For example if you pass it in with the render call, with a name such as "myObject":

```
myTemplate.render(myData, {myObject: SomeObject});
```

then you can reference it as in `~myObject`:

```
<img ... src="{{: ~fltrOAMnImgs_hlp(Images, ~myObject)}}">
```

See also this related answer: [Trying to run a function on an array in a, for loop, using jsrender](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19666457/trying-to-run-a-function-on-an-array-in-a-for-loop-using-jsrender/19699672#19699672)

Comment: Unfortunatley it seems when I try to pass this: var AdUnit = {};
 AdUnit.Id = 6;
 $( "#MOBILELARGE" ).html( $( "#mobileLargeTemplate" ).render( currentOffer, AdUnit ) ); the var AdUnit.Id comes up undefined when the template runs

Comment: If you are passing in the AdUnit as options, the contextual variable will be ~id. If you want the whole AdUnit object to be accessed as a variable ~AdUnit, then you need to pass it in as .render( currentOffer, {AdUnit: AdUnit} ) - so AdUnit is a property of the options object you are passing in. (As in my example above with ~myObject).